# Clicking any where in the OneNote, Taking the cursor to the top

Tags: macos, onenote

Not Sure what happened after the new update in mac, Whenever i'm clicking anywhere out of the page in oneNote and clicking anywhere, it's taking the cursor on the very top left corner. It's very annoying since have to scroll down to the page again and again.

I have gone through the microsoft official answer, but didn't get any concrete answer.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/annoying-cursor-offset-in-onenote/3f39ee3e-cc11-4160-b3d2-baff9638fe4d

Answer (score 0):

***with new mac update, they have added an option click in the scroll bar select the option Jump to the spot that's clicked, have fixed this issue.***

[image]